# asp.net mvc LINQ TO SQL handling database events (alerts/feed)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, logging

Recently I did one web site (www.ramtajogi.com) using asp.net mvc, linq to sql .
I have used repository pattern to get data from the database. Now everything is working fine.
But the new requirement is to record all the events (on poetry book created, on poem added or when a new comment is posted to any poem. What is the best way to implement it. 
Should I change my existing classes and do or is there any better way to do it.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: What makes this question interesting.

Comment: Are you referring to logging actions?

Comment: @XSaint32 no its not about logging. I am using elmah for that. Actually site is for poems where user can add poems or can comment on user poems. So want to record who did what so that I should be able to display it as feed.

Comment: You need to provide more information regarding what your classes look like now and what database structure you have in place.

Comment: as I see it you probably don't need a 'log' for every action the website has, but only for a few actions which would then end up in a list showing what's new or something like that. could be good to see the code you use to create a poem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a way to log across different actions:

Try this: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Logging_with_ASPNET_MVC_Action_Filters.aspx

Comment: its realted to database logging not about actions logging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to go the "SQL Trigger" road? I know it's a much debated subject, but it allows you to log without changing any of your existing code.
I'm not sure about its impact, but if the triggers only do some inserts into a log table, I guess it should be quite low.

Comment: thanks Gidon. I know that is good way, but just want to avoid creating scripts and stuff for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

Actually I created another table for alerts and added one record for every event.

Regards
Parminder